# concatenate the rows into one with multiple left joins

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I have a query as below:

```
select 
    a.person_name ,
    f.speciality,
    a.email,
    a.phone, 
    a.address
    na.descrition 'nationality',
    ci.description 'city'
    from person a
    left join lookup na on a.Country_id = na.lookup_id and na.lookup_type='FND_COUNTRIES'
    left join lookup ci on a.City_id = ci.lookup_id and ci.lookup_type='IM_CITIES'
    left join speciality pe on a.id = pe.person_id 
    left join np_speciality f on pe.speciality_id = f.speciality_id
    , 
    person_dtl b

    where a.id = b.person_id
```

result of this

```
person_name        speciality          email        phone    nationality    city  
    a                   1                                           20          30
    a                   20                                          20          30
    a                   30                                          20          30
```

I need the below result:

```
   person_name        speciality          email        phone    nationality    city  
    a                   1,20,30                                     20          30
```

hOw can i achieve the same

found answers for the same but its not able to solve the issue because of multiple left join in the query

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Simulating group\_concat MySQL function in Microsoft SQL Server 2005?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/451415/simulating-group-concat-mysql-function-in-microsoft-sql-server-2005)

Answer (score 0):

You can replicate a `group_concat` type function using `stuff` and `for xml`.  Without sample data this is obviously untested, but should be near enough what you need:

```
select p.person_name
      ,stuff((select ', ' + f.speciality
              from np_speciality f
              where pe.speciality_id = f.speciality_id
              for xml path('')
              )
             ,1,2,'') as speciality
      ,p.email
      ,p.phone
      ,p.address
      ,na.descrition as nationality
      ,ci.description as city
from person as p
    join person_dtl as pd
        on p.id = pd.person_id
    left join lookup na
        on p.Country_id = na.lookup_id
            and na.lookup_type = 'FND_COUNTRIES'
    left join lookup ci
        on p.City_id = ci.lookup_id
            and ci.lookup_type = 'IM_CITIES'
    left join speciality pe
        on p.id = pe.person_id
```

---

`stuff` replaces a part of a string defined by a start and end character number with another defined string.  In this case, starting at character `1`, replace `2` characters with a blank string.  This is required because of the way the `for xml` works:

`for xml` produces an `xml` string of your output.  By specifying no `path` value and a `', '` delimiter we get a string of values separated by a comma and space, with a leading comma and space at the beginning, which is removed by the `stuff`.

I would also strongly recommend you use modern `join` syntax and meaningful alias in all your scripts.  Mixing `join` conditions with comma separated tables as well as `a, b, c, etc` table alias just makes your code hard to read and maintain.